# WCF asynchronous server side - proper implementation

Tags: c#, wcf, async-await

I writing some WCF services and I want to write them in the most efficient way possible. That means that both server side and client side will expose async operations.

**Client side**

I am aware that on the client side contracts, I can expose async operations just by adding "Assync" suffix:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    string GetData(int value);

    [OperationContract]
    Task<string> GetDataAsync(int value);
}
```

**Server side**

The server side is not as obvious to me. On the server side I would like to keep only Async operations:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    Task<string> GetDataAsync(int value);
}
```

According to [How to: Implement an Asynchronous Service Operation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/how-to-implement-an-asynchronous-service-operation) I should use IAssyncResult:

```
  [OperationContractAttribute(AsyncPattern=true)]
  IAsyncResult BeginServiceAsyncMethod(string msg, AsyncCallback callback, object asyncState);
```

This, however, seems tedious.

**Why is the purpose of using IAssyncResult instead of Task-based async operations and what is the proper way of implementing async server side in WCF?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/) (emphasis mine):

> Asynchronous Programming Model (APM) pattern (also called the `IAsyncResult` pattern), where asynchronous operations require Begin and End methods (for example, `BeginWrite` and `EndWrite` for asynchronous write operations). **This pattern is no longer recommended for new development**. For more information, see [Asynchronous Programming Model (APM)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/asynchronous-programming-model-apm).

versus

> Task-based Asynchronous Pattern (TAP), which uses a single method to represent the initiation and completion of an asynchronous operation. TAP was introduced in the .NET Framework 4 and **is the recommended approach to asynchronous programming in the .NET Framework**. The `async` and `await` keywords in C# and the `Async` and `Await` operators in Visual Basic Language add language support for TAP. For more information, see [Task-based Asynchronous Pattern (TAP)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/task-based-asynchronous-pattern-tap).

So:

The article you are reading comes from the pre- .NET 4.0 era (so it is quite old). Use `Task`s and forget that `IAsyncResult` exists.